# Getting error while I am defining multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs

Here is my piece of code in which I am trying to define multiple controllers in the JS file:

```
var app = angular.module("Contact",[]);

app.controller("ContactCtrl", ConCtrl);
app.controller("HeaderCtrl", Header);

function ConCtrl(){
}

function Header(){
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. What's the error ?

Comment: You need to describe the error. Maybe when you initialised the controller in HTML, you typed the wrong name? e.g. `ng-controller="ConCtrl"` instead of `ng-controller="ContactCtrl"`

Comment: you can make module for controllers like `angular.module('app', ['app.controllers'])` and then use them like this   `angular.module('app.controllers')   
.controller('ContactCtrl' // controller function here) .controller( "HeaderCtrl" // controller function here); `

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't use from {} to define the top controller and `;` can't use for the end of the controller when `function(){}` is defined. 
You can use:

```
 var myApp = angular.module("demoApp", []);

    myApp.controller("CtrlOne", function ($scope) {

        $scope.inputData = "Tutorials Park";

        $scope.reverseData = function () {
        $scope.inputData = $scope.inputData.split("").reverse().join("");
        }
    });

    myApp.controller("CtrlTwo", function ($scope) {

        $scope.inputData = "angularjs";

        $scope.changeUpperCase = function () {
            $scope.inputData = $scope.inputData.toUpperCase();
        };
    });
```

Name the module to write with a small letter.

Comment: Because you can't use from {} to define top controller.